# No text shown in label windows forms

Tags: c#

Im making a hangman game with 2 player the second player types his name in a textbox and clicks ready up to enter game
Here is the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Methods.displayName_playertwo;


            if (!checkBox1.Checked && !checkBox2.Checked && textBox1.Text != "\0")
                button1.Enabled = false;

            else
            {

                button1.Enabled = true;

            }
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {

                Form4 f = new Form4();
                this.Hide();
                f.Show();
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                
                Form11 f = new Form11();
                this.Hide();
                f.Show();
            }
        }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM98M.jpg
Then i want to show it in a label

```
label14.Text = "Score of " + Methods.displayName_playertwo + ":  " + User.score_Player2.ToString();
```

But its only showing score of:0
Its not showing the player 2 name

Comment: You can put a breakpoint and check the value of `Methods.displayName_playertwo` when assigning `label14.Text`.

Comment: You may want to think about naming things correctly. If you already reached Label14 and Form11 losing track of what does what is presumably part of your problem here understanding what is happening.